# Are Routers and Router Extensions the Same?

Tags: wifi

Are routers and their extensions connected? To help explain, let's say a download goes through the extender, would that download also slow down the network it's extending, or are they practically two different routers? When connecting to a network, the extender and the router are listed separaetly, so does that mean that they are different?